# How to set port and host for php function mail()

Tags: php, email, port, host

I have set up a website at online domain, and the php mail() function is not working. The technician tells me i have to set the port = 2525 and host = mailout.one.com. Can someone tells me how to set the right port and host?

i'm not using xampp, thus php.ini does not exist

Thanks.

Comment: where you set it depends on what code you are using to send the mail

Comment: that setting goes in php.ini or use awesome https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: i'm not using xampp, thus php.ini does not exist

Answer (score 5):

You can set it at runtime for testing.  But if it works you'll want modify your php.ini file.
Put this at the top of your mailer script to test.

```
ini_set('SMTP','mailout.one.com' );
ini_set('smtp_port',2525);
```

To change it in your php.ini, you can just search for 'SMTP' or 'smtp_port'.

Comment: IF he is using php's mail()

Comment: As he stated: "I have set up a website at online domain, and the php mail() function is not working"

Comment: i'm not using xampp, thus php.ini does not exist

Comment: @user3383140 php.ini exists for every kind of php install i have ever seen, what kind of hosting is this? it would be in most cases setup by the host  in the beginning.

Comment: where can i found the php.ini file?

Comment: depends on the hosting type.

Comment: the technician told me the php.ini is not assessible

Comment: that's what i would expect for most low end hosts. but they should already have the mail server detail's set up for you.